# Update .bashrc from provisioning shell script with Vagrant

Tags: linux, bash, vagrant

I'm trying to add some additional lines to .bashrc in my home directory from the provisioning shell script when launching a new instance with Vagrant.

In the shell script I have:

```
set -x

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install vim

echo "source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh">> ~/.bashrc
echo "source /usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh">> ~/.bashrc
```

However after completion nothing has been written to .bashrc.

This is a cut down version of the full script the intention of which is to install Ruby/Rails.

Comment: Add a debug echo in between the additions to the bashrc file, my best guess is your script somehow skips it because of a control structure.

Comment: I get the following in stdout when the bash script is hitting the lines that are trying to echo into .bashrc, they're getting run - is it possible that they're being echoed to a .bashrc file that is not in /home/vagrant ?

    ==> default: ++ echo 'source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh'
    ==> default: ++ echo 'source /usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh'
    ==> default: ++ . /root/.bashrc
    ==> default: +++ '[' -z '' ']'
    ==> default: +++ return

Comment: If they are you can easily avoid it by replacing the `~` by the full path from `/`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to give the full path to the file.

E.g.

```
echo "source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh" >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
```

Comment: THIS is the correct answer that a dozen other SO threads don't have. The ~ does not resolve as expected apparently when running the vagrant provisioner.

Comment: That's because the provisioner is running as root, `~` refers to `/root`, not `/home/vagrant`

Comment: I have following error ` /root/home/vagrant/.bashrc: No such file or directory`

Answer (score -1):

Add these lines to .bashrc

```
if [ -f /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh ]; then
    . /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh
fi
```

It will textually include the script into .bashrc and execute it when opening a new shell.

Comment: I don't want to add the lines manually - I want to add them via a shell script.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Add these lines to the .bashrc and the script chruby.py should be executed upon opening a new shell... My answer doesn't suggest you to copy the lines from chruby.sh and paste them in .bashrc in any way... If you are sure the file exists you can put `echo ". /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh" >> ~/.bashrc` in your script.

Answer (score -2):

Try this for your last 2 lines - it should give you exactly what you need.

```
echo "source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh" >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc

echo "source /usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh" >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
```

Comment: 'source' will try and execute the lines of the script.

Comment: This would concatenate the two files, what I'm after is adding the line "source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh" to the end of .bashrc so that it executes when I open bash.  As per the steps on here - http://ryanbigg.com/2014/10/ubuntu-ruby-ruby-install-chruby-and-you//

Comment: OK - now I understand what you're trying to do. If you just type that line from the shell console - does it work? I tried it both ways and it works fine. Try setting the target .bashrc using the full path name, instead of "~/". I think my solution above will do the same thing, but I agree will clutter up bashrc